# Why I am not able to use "conda activate" command?

Tags: anaconda, conda

```
error: argument command: invalid choice: 'activate'
```

---

1. OS: Windows 11
2. Build: Anaconda3-2023.07-2-Windows-x86_64.exe
3. The path to conda: `C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts`, is already added to system variable.

---

While using Git Bash, I created an virtual environment:

```
conda create -n textS python=3.8
```

I even checked whether it was created successfully or not:

```
$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\ProgramData\anaconda3
textS                    C:\Users\Divyansh Gupta\.conda\envs\textS
```

but when I tried to "activate" it, it gave error:

```
$ conda activate textS
```

Error:

```
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-v] [--no-plugins] [-V] COMMAND ...
conda-script.py: error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: 'activate' (choose from 'clean', 'compare', 'config', 'create', 'info', 'init', 'install', 'list', 'notices', 'package', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'rename', 'run', 'search', 'update', 'upgrade', 'build', 'content-trust', 'convert', 'debug', 'develop', 'doctor', 'index', 'inspect', 'metapackage', 'render', 'repoquery', 'skeleton', 'verify', 'env', 'repo', 'token', 'pack', 'server')
```

I checked online, and some sources said to run `conda init` command which will solve the problem, but even after I successfully ran the `init` command, the `activate` command didn't work.

Comment: Have you used `conda init bash` in the Git Bash terminal? and restarted? I think on Windows `conda init` alone will default to the cmd.exe or Powershell init, not bash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to the [comment from merv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376509/why-i-am-not-able-to-use-conda-activate-command/77400829#comment136435174_77376509):

> Have you used **conda init bash** in the Git Bash terminal? and restarted? I think on Windows **conda init** alone will default to the cmd.exe or Powershell init, not bash.

I used `conda init bash` and restarted my Git bash terminal; afterwards, the environment activated successfully.